ClickHouse cluster connection timeout and address errors using spring JDBC
We are trying to connect to a ClickHouse cluster (containing 4 nodes and 3 ClickHouse-keepers) using the JDBC connector. When I test the performance with 100, 200, or 300 threads (users), after some time (~5 minutes), I encounter connection read timeout errors (in production environment) or "Address already in use" errors (in local environment) although nothing is in use.
Currently, I have three tables:

main_table
replication_table (2 shards, 2 replicas per shard)
buffer_table (to mitigate "too many parts" errors)

Data is first inserted into the buffer_table, which then flushes out to the replicated_table, from where the data is distributed to all the replicas (4 nodes, depending on the shard key).
Here is the configuration used while connecting:
@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.url}")
private String url;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.driver-class-name}")
private String driverClass;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.connection-timeout}")
private String connectionTimeout;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.socket-timeout}")
private String socketTimeout;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.ssl}")
private String ssl;

@Value("${clickhouse.datasource.load-balancing-policy}")
private String loadBalancingPolicy;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("user", username.trim());
    properties.setProperty("password", password.trim());
    properties.setProperty("connection_timeout", connectionTimeout.trim());
    properties.setProperty("socket_timeout", socketTimeout.trim());
    properties.setProperty("ssl", ssl.trim());
    properties.setProperty("load_balancing_policy", loadBalancingPolicy.trim());

    ClickHouseDataSource dataSource = new ClickHouseDataSource(url.trim(), properties);
    return dataSource;
}


Configuration properties:
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=200
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true

clickhouse.datasource.url=jdbc:clickhouse://server1:8123,server2:8123,server3:8123,server4:8123/dap_dev
clickhouse.datasource.driver-class-name=com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver
clickhouse.datasource.connection-timeout=30000
clickhouse.datasource.socket-timeout=300000
clickhouse.datasource.ssl=false
clickhouse.datasource.load-balancing-policy=roundRobin

Please let me know if there is any property or something else I am doing wrong that is causing ClickHouse to throw these timeout errors.

Hi Shivan - could you please explain why you are using so many concurrent threads? ClickHouse works best using large batch sizes (10000+ rows per INSERT) - each individual INSERT thread will result in 1 part. This is likely the cause of TOO_MANY_PARTS, and probably in turn causing performance bottlenecks due to parts merging too slowly. My recommendation would be to first reduce to lower number of threads to 1 or 10, and then can reuse threads for multiple queries: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/java#multiple-queries - should also evaluate server performance via Advanced Dashboard

Hi @ThomO'Connor
In our scenario, there are very frequent writes, and we aim to achieve at least 200 TPS. For batch insertion, I'm using a buffer table where we buffer around 10,000 rows, thus resolving the parts problem.
However, the issue now lies with the JDBC connection. After 2-3 minutes, it reports a connection timeout. I initially thought the issue was due to an insufficient number of threads, so I increased the threads handling the service-side hits, but the problem persists.

I see, thanks for explaining Shivan. It is a good idea to reuse each thread some, so using a connection pool and maintaining a set of established connections is a good idea. This reduces the number of new connections that must be established (TCP overhead is significant if opening/closing the connection every time). However, if the connection is idle, it can timeout - some users will reuse a connection for a defined number of INSERTs or queries, for example 10, then close & reopen that connection - this method provides a good balance of reuse while making sure connections are not left open
